# Is there an equivalent to Android.Util.Log in Xamarin for iOS?

Tags: xamarin

I'm working on a project in Xamarin that will run on both Android and iOS. Xamarin's Android libraries have support for Android.Util.Log, but I haven't found its equivalent in iOS after some quick searches. What I have found seems to suggest that all iOS really has is support for `Console.WriteLine()` and other methods of the `Console` class. Is this the case, or did I miss something obvious?

(That's actually fine for my case, I know there's efforts to get log4net levels of sophistication on Xamarin but for this stage of my project I only care about getting a very simple logging abstraction in place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS users can use NSLog(string), but for cross platform development I'd suggest System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() and overloads.